# Is it possible to write VS Code extension that modifies tasks.json and launch.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to create my own extension that would provide predefined configuration for debugger (launch.json) and a predefined set of tasks (tasks.json).

Right now I have vs code configured in those 2 files but there are lot of hardcodes in many places that will vary across different projects. So ideally I would like to have a plugin that eg reads one configuration file and applies all that stuff to "tasks.json" and "launch.json".

Wondering if that's even possible with vs code extensions API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this with variables defined in `settings.json`.  You can define your own custom settings in `settings.json` (either user or workspace settings):

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,  // normal settings defined by the editor and plugins
  "foo.bar": "baz" // custom setting
}
```

You can then reference this setting inside `tasks.json` or `launch.json` using string interpolation as `"${config:foo.bar}"`.

I'm not sure where this is documented, but I found a reference to this in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/11291

**Update:**

I've created a test repo at https://github.com/boyvinall/vscode-c-dbg. When I invoke the "run" task within `tasks.json`, I get the following output:

[image]

Using through `launch.json` with my current configuration doesn't seem to work with the "gdb" configuration, although the "cppdbg" configuration does seem to work ok:

[image: enter [...] "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"...stackoverflow is annoying]

NB, in case it's important, I'm running vscode v1.8.1

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I don't get any "unknown reference" kind of error however seems like the "${config.foo.bar}" defined in settings.json resolves to an empty string. Also VS code is giving a warning "unknown configuration setting" in settings.json file.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to a github repo that shows this working.  Are you able to run that one?

Comment: That one is working, it's because in settings.json the "config" prefix should be ommited, i missed that. Do You know whether it's possible through extensions api to predefine tasks?

Comment: Hmm, not sure about the predefined tasks bit - sorry, I missed that earlier.  I'll try to poke around and will add comment here if I manage to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Code:1.15.1

settings.json (.vscode folder current dir)

```
{
"foo.bar": "baz" // custom setting 
}
```

launch.json (example)

```
{
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/${config:foo.bar}.exe"
}
```

I was looking around found it. But it was out date and was trying to figure it out. Until the helper visual studio code hint gave me the information when mouse hover/over the strings.

> "${config.foo.bar}"

does not work.

> "${config:foo.bar}"

does work.